# How using MSBuild Copy task? and Making target as lowercase filename?

Tags: msbuild-task

How do I use the MSBuild Copy task? Also, it is seems to be making target as lowercase in the filename - is this right?

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(DATA)" DestinationFiles="@(DATA->'$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\BuildWin32\data\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
```

I mean, the part "%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" become lower case in the final file name and folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think that %(RecursiveDir) is like an array.

So if you have DIRA with files file1.xml and files2.xml and DIRB with file file3.xml (obtained with something similar to C:\dir***.xml)... the copy task will make a substitution for each dir & file of the array and copy all the wanted files.